# ARP packets never routed?

Tags: networking, security, arp, arp-poisoning

is it true ARP only works in single broadcast domain and arp packets are not routed frm 1 network to another ?

can any one give me any example or any source of info for this

hoping for positive response.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ARP was first defined in [RFC 826](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc826.html). It is evident from the content that discovering the MAC address of a target IP-address is only useful, for packet delivery, within a single local broadcast domain.

Answer (score 3):

ARP packets are a Layer 2 frame.  To route anything, you need IP addresses, which are contained in a Layer 3 packet.  An ARP packet simply does not contain enough information to be routed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is basically correct. One can however proxy arps, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_ARP.

Answer (score 1):

But why would you *want* to route ARP, it's only of use on the target segment - what would you hope to achieve?